# Set grid width when using fillwithgrid (exam package)

Tags: indentation, exam, grids

How can I set the width of the grid that is displayed with the command `\fillwithgrid{50mm}`? I am using questions with parts. The grid always gets the current text width, so assuming I have question 1 a) the grid is indented the same amount as the text for question 1 a). I want the grid to be at least at full text width.

I tried

```
\question
\begin{parts}
  \part[8]
    \makebox[\textwidth]{\smallskip \fillwithgrid{115mm}}
\end{parts}
```

which produces the error

> You can't use `\hrule' here except with leaders.

**SOLUTION:** (kind of)

See [Andrew Swann's](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/361921/85066) answer for a solution when using a fixed height within `\fillwithgrid{}`. However, I found a workaround using `\adjustwidth` which seems to be the best solution when using `\fillwithgrid{\stretch{1}}` instead of a fixed height:

```
\documentclass[addpoints,12pt]{exam}

\begin{document}

\begin{questions}
    \question
    \begin{parts}
        \part[5] Solve: $2x+3=5$

            \begin{adjustwidth}{-20mm}{0mm}
            \smallskip \fillwithgrid{115mm}}
            \end{adjustwidth}
    \end{parts}
\end{questions}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]!  it is best to complete code snippet to complete minimal documents that others can try to compile.  For your question, you should use `\parbox` rather than `\makebox`.

Comment: Thank you. I tried this but it didn't work. I edited the question accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `\fillwithgrid` uses `\textwidth`.  You can set it locally in the given group as follows, note need to box this up:

```
\documentclass[addpoints,12pt]{exam}

\begin{document}

\begin{questions}
    \question
    \begin{parts}
        \part[5] Solve: $2x+3=5$

        \smallskip
        {\setlength{\textwidth}{1.5\textwidth}
        \fillwithgrid{115mm}}
      \part[5] Solve: $2x+3=5$

        \smallskip
        {\setlength{\textwidth}{1.5\textwidth}
        \fillwithgrid{\stretch{1}}}
    \end{parts}
  \end{questions}

\end{document}
```

[image: Sample output]

This gives you grid running off the right-hand side of the page.  You can move it left by adding `\hspace` with a negative dimension, before the group.

Comment: This works great... Until I use `\fillwithgrid{\stretch{1}}` instead of `\fillwithgrid{115mm}`. I know I didn't use `\stretch{1}` in my example code but do you know a solution that works with it?

Comment: Boxing this up like this won't work with the `\stretch` commands, as the glue is fixed by the box.  Your `adjustwidth` solution is probably the best way in this case.

Comment: OK, the `\parbox` was not needed at all, just a group.  Answer updated.